# Winforms DataBind to Control's Visible Property

Tags: winforms, data-binding, .net-3.5, bindingsource

Are there any known issues when databinding to a control's visible property?

The control is always NOT visible regardless of what my property is.

```
Public ReadOnly Property IsRibbonCategory() As Boolean
    Get
        Return True
    End Get
End Property
```

I tried the control's text property and other properties and they seem to work correctly.

I am trying to set a Panel's visible property.

Comment: how are you binding? with a bindingsource control or declaritively?

Comment: This might have something to do with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2570153/2455604

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Workaround: Set the Visible property on the BindingComplete event.

I had same issue setting a label's Visible property - always stays false, even though setting the Enabled property works fine.

Answer (score 8):

I've found that life is better if you assume that binding to a control's Visible property is broken, despite the fact that it sometimes works. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327305, which says as much (and while the KB article applies to .NET 1.0 and 1.1, it still seems to be a problem in at least 2.0).

I created a utility class for creating bindings which, among other things, gave me a centralized place to add a work-around. Instead of actually creating a binding on Visible it does two things:

1. It subscribes to the data source's INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event and sets the Visible value as appropriate when the event is raised.
2. It sets the initial value of Visible according to the current data source value.

This required a little reflection code, but wasn't too bad. It is critical that you don't bind the Visible property **and** do the work-around or it won't work.

Answer (score 5):

I just hit this issue in .NET 4.7.1 and Visual Studio 2017. To fix it, I changed the `Visible` property on my control to be initially set to `True`, as I had it as `False` previously.

Comment: Wow this worked, thanks a lot! I will try it on every control in the future :P

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

- Be sure you've instantiated the class that has the IsRibbonCategory property
- Did you set the datasource of property of the binding source to the instance of the class
- The datasource update mode should be on "on validation"
- Make sure you didn't set the visible property manually to false on the control

Hope that helps. Can you post more code?

Comment: I have checked all of those, but no dice. One question, have you tried databinding to visible property and it worked?

Comment: Yes. VS 2008/Winforms. What event do you use to set the datasource of the bindingsource control?

Comment: Have you tried calling bindingsource.CurrencyManager.Refresh in the form's load event?

Comment: No, that didn't work. I will try to put a small prototype together

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to use a Component to databind to a control's visiblity property instead of directly binding to the control's visibility property.
See below code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
  public class ControlVisibilityBinding : Component
  {
    private static readonly object EventControlChanged = new object();
    private static readonly object EventVisibleChanged = new object();

    private System.Windows.Forms.Control _control;
    private bool _visible = true;

    public event EventHandler VisibleChanged
    {
        add { Events.AddHandler(EventVisibleChanged, value); }
        remove { Events.RemoveHandler(EventVisibleChanged, value); }
    }

    public event EventHandler ControlChanged
    {
        add { Events.AddHandler(EventControlChanged, value); }
        remove { Events.RemoveHandler(EventControlChanged, value); }
    }

    public ControlVisibilityBinding()
    {
    }

    public ControlVisibilityBinding(IContainer container)
    {
        container.Add(this);
    }

    [DefaultValue(null)]
    public System.Windows.Forms.Control Control
    {
        get { return _control; }
        set
        {
            if(_control == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            WireControl(_control, false);
            _control = value;
            if(_control != null)
            {
                _control.Visible = _visible;
            }
            WireControl(_control, true);
            OnControlChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool Visible
    {
        get { return _visible; }
        set
        {
            if(_visible != value)
            {
                _visible = value;
            }
            if(Control != null)
            {
                Control.Visible = _visible;
            }
            OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    private void WireControl(Control control, bool subscribe)
    {
        if(control == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if(subscribe)
        {
            control.VisibleChanged += Control_VisibleChanged;
        }
        else
        {
            control.VisibleChanged -= Control_VisibleChanged;
        }
    }

    private void Control_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    protected virtual void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler subscribers = (EventHandler)Events[EventVisibleChanged];
        if(subscribers != null)
        {
            subscribers(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnControlChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler subscribers = (EventHandler)Events[EventControlChanged];
        if(subscribers != null)
        {
            subscribers(this, e);
        }
    }
}

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        using(Form form = new Form())
        using(FlowLayoutPanel groupBoxLayoutPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel())
        using(RadioButton visibleButton = new RadioButton())
        using(RadioButton hiddenButton = new RadioButton())
        using(GroupBox groupBox = new GroupBox())
        using(Label text = new Label())
        using(ControlVisibilityBinding visibilityBinding = new ControlVisibilityBinding())
        using(TextBox inputTextBox = new TextBox())
        {
            groupBoxLayoutPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            groupBoxLayoutPanel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
            groupBoxLayoutPanel.AutoSize = true;
            groupBoxLayoutPanel.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;

            visibleButton.Text = "Show Label";
            visibleButton.AutoSize = true;
            hiddenButton.Text = "Hide Label";
            hiddenButton.AutoSize = true;
            groupBoxLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(visibleButton);
            groupBoxLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(hiddenButton);

            inputTextBox.Text = "Enter Label Text Here";
            inputTextBox.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

            groupBox.AutoSize = true;
            groupBox.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            groupBox.Controls.Add(groupBoxLayoutPanel);
            groupBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            text.AutoSize = true;
            text.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            text.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
            text.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            text.Font = new Font(text.Font.FontFamily, text.Font.Size * 1.25f, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
            text.DataBindings.Add("Text", inputTextBox, "Text", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);

            visibilityBinding.Control = text;
            visibleButton.DataBindings.Add("Checked", visibilityBinding, "Visible", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            Binding binding = hiddenButton.DataBindings.Add("Checked", visibilityBinding, "Visible", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            ConvertEventHandler invertConverter = (sender, e) => e.Value = !((bool)e.Value);
            binding.Format += invertConverter;
            binding.Parse += invertConverter;

            form.Controls.Add(inputTextBox);
            form.Controls.Add(text);
            form.Controls.Add(groupBox);
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is my turn around, it may be stupid but it worked many times.

I put one **Panel** control in my form, I make it to **Fill** my form and I put everything in that Panel. All the controls I bind the **Visible** property see their visibility change according to the objects in my DataGridView.

[image: Form structure]

Answer (score 0):

Try manual binding in Form Load.

Found that binding to a property in a BindingSource object in the form designer didn't work. Had to set the binding in code-behind (Form's Load event) instead.

Probably due the property bound to Visible was being set to False momentarily, as the Button/Panel/control was being initialized, as the Form was loading, before the BindingSource was fully initialized with either a true or false value.

Here is a manual binding example that worked for me:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    button1.DataBindings.Add("Visible", someBindingSource, "SomePropertyOfObject", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation);
}
```