# Binding.IsBinding = false and Biding.BindingManagerBase = null on ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm trying to extend `ContextMenuStrip` (I'm reusing it quite often) so it'd be bind with `FormSettings` (which automatically store settings later). For example whether to overwrite or append file when exporting something.

#### FormSettings:

```
internal sealed partial class FormSettings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static FormSettings defaultInstance = ((FormSettings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized( new FormSettings() )));


    private void OnPropertyChanged( string propertyName )
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default instance
    /// </summary>
    public static FormSettings Default
    {
        get { return defaultInstance; }
    }

    private FormSettings()
        : base( "column_settings" )
    {
    }

    ~FormSettings()
    {
        defaultInstance.Save();
    }

    [Bindable( true )]
    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute( "False" )]
    public bool ExportCSVOverwrite
    {
        get { return (bool)this["ExportCSVOverwrite"]; }
        set
        {
            if (value != (bool)this["ExportCSVOverwrite"]) {
                this["ExportCSVOverwrite"] = value;
                OnPropertyChanged( "ExportCSVOverwrite" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### My extended context menu strip:

```
public class MinimalExample : ContextMenuStrip, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool _export_overwrite = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Triggered when some property gets changed
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable( true )]
    [Category( "Action" )]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [Browsable( true )]
    [Category( "Behavior" )]
    [Bindable( true )]
    public bool ExportOverWrite
    {
        get { return _export_overwrite; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _export_overwrite) {
                _export_overwrite = value;
                OnPropertyChanged( "ExportOverWrite" );
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Triggered when property gets changed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    virtual protected void OnPropertyChanged( object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) {
            PropertyChanged( sender, e );
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Triggered when property gets changed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="property_name"></param>
    protected void OnPropertyChanged( string property_name )
    {
        OnPropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( property_name ) );
    }

    public MinimalExample()
    {
        var tmp = DataBindings.Add( "ExportOverWrite", FormSettings.Default, "ExportCSVOverwrite", 
                           false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, false );
        // Breakpoint here
    }
}
```

But when I try to debug `DataBindings` all bindings have [`IsBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.isbinding.aspx) set to `false` and [`BindingManagerBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.bindingmanagerbase.aspx) is also `null`. So biding to `FormSettings` doesn't work.

What am I missing?

#### Edit:

I found that the possible issue is in context menu is not displayed at the time data binding is created, but none of solutions [I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523778/forcing-a-checkbox-bound-to-a-datasource-to-update-when-it-has-not-been-viewed-y) works.

#### Edit #2

If I make `FormSettings` bindable and add bindings on its side it works as expected until I try to create second instance of `ContextMenuStrip` which triggers `ArgumentException`: `This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found working workaround about this problem (this will cause `DataBidings` to be initialized when all controls are set for the form):

```
    protected override void OnOpened( EventArgs e )
    {
        base.OnOpened( e );
        DataBindings.Clear();
        InitializeDataBindings();
    }
```

It works but it's just kludge... If anyone has better (more systematic) solution I'll be glad.

Comment: `DataBinding` in `winforms` is very complicated, sometimes you just know **this works** but you can't explain **why it works**.