# Start a form's message loop without calling show()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-2.0

I have a `System.Windows.Forms.Form` window, that needs to get events delivered to it with `Control.Invoke()`. However, the messages are not getting delivered prior to calling `Show()` on the form.

In order to work around this, I tried this kludge in the form's constructor:

```
this.Show();
this.Hide();
```

This works, and the messages are now getting delivered. However, this results in a window flashing in and out when the form is constructed. Is there a more elegant way to achieve what I want?

I'm working with .NET 2.0 (a newer version is not allowed).

Comment: Yuck, in 2.0 id be happy i found an answer. Play around with suspend layout or suspend draw.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `this.CreateControl()` or calling `this.Handle` would do that I guess.

Comment: Possible hack: Before calling Show/Hide, temporarily set the top/left coordinates to something negative, moving the form off the display surface.

Comment: May I ask what you're trying to achieve? You may get better answer in that case.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It's a window that needs to stay hidden unless there's reason to show it. The window manages that stuff all by itself and it's part of a class library. All the user of that library needs to do is instantiate it, and when something interesting happens, the window shows itself. The window knows whether something interesting happened or not, by subscribing to events of other objects and those events are always delivered with Control.Invoke().

Comment: Another "hacK" would be to set the forms opacity to 0 before calling Show(), and then after hiding it, set it back to full opacity.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this old question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523778/forcing-a-checkbox-bound-to-a-datasource-to-update-when-it-has-not-been-viewed-y) that tries to solve the same problem.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Just reading `this.Handle` is way simpler though :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criterion of `Control.Invoke` is that `Handle` has to be created and nothing else. You don't need to call `Show` and `Hide` instead force creating the `Handle`.

```
Form yourForm = new Form();
var handle =  pbForm.Handle;//Force create handle
```

From this point you can able to call `yourForm.Invoke`

**Note:** Your form's `Load` event and `Shown` event will not be fired unless you show the form. So any code depends on those events will break.

If your code depends on `Load` or `Shown` events, you need a hack. You need to make the form very small so that user can't notice it (Probably size of 1,1), then call `Show` and `Hide`. Later at some point when you need to show the form to user you can set a decent `Size`.

Comment: Yep, I tried both CreateControl() as well as reading `this.Handle` (from your original comment.) Only the latter works. I've simply done `var bogus = this.Handle;` in the ctor. Though I'm a bit worried about the optimizer. I assume that the side effects of the `Handle` getter will prevent this from getting optimized out? (Btw, the `Load` and `Shown` events are not important in my case.)

Comment: @NikosC. Am not expert in this topic. To be on safer side cheat the jit and compiler optimizers by pretending to use the `Handle` somehow. Let's say `Console.WriteLine(this.Handle);` which can't be optimized.

Comment: Hm, I guess I'll assign it to a `volatile` member in this case. Too bad `volatile` is not allowed on local vars.